# Suma de arreglo me devuelve valores concatenados

Tags: javascript, array

**El programa recibe valores y lo inserta en un array hasta que recibe un valor negativo, cuando es asi deve devolver la suma del arreglo, ahora cuando lo hace solo me devuelve los valores concatenado sabran por que???**

```html
var arreglo = [];

function suma(arreglo){
    let suma = 0;
    arreglo.forEach(function(numero){
        suma += numero;
    });
    document.write(suma);
};

do{
    var valida = true;
    var inserta = prompt('Inserta un numero');
    if(inserta < 0){
        valida = false;

        // Obtenos la suma del arreglo
        suma(arreglo);
        

    }else{
        arreglo.unshift(inserta);
    };
}while(valida == true);
```

Comment: Buen día. Si alguna de las respuestas resolvió tu pregunta, por favor márcala como respuesta correcta. Esto ayuda a otros usuarios que puedan tener la misma pregunta y ayuda a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método "prompt" retorna un string y no un numero, por lo que antes de agregarlo a tu arreglo debes de convertirlo a un numero, puedes usar parseInt.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte!

Answer (score 2):

Buen día,

Tu variable `inserta` recibe un `string`. En JavaScript puedes concatenar `string` utilizando el operador `+` por lo que al realizar tu `suma()` te concatena los `string`

```
var inserta = prompt('Inserta un numero');
```

Debes hacer que el valor que recibe `inserta` sea numérico, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
var inserta = parseInt(prompt('Inserta un numero'));
```

El código funcionando está a continuación:

```js
var arreglo = [];

function suma(arreglo){
    let suma = 0;
    arreglo.forEach(function(numero){
        suma += numero;
    });
    document.write(suma);
};

do{
    var valida = true;
    var inserta = parseInt(prompt('Inserta un numero'));
    if(inserta < 0){
        valida = false;

        // Obtenos la suma del arreglo
        suma(arreglo);
        

    }else{
        arreglo.unshift(inserta);
    };
}while(valida == true);
```

Comment: No lo habia tomado en cuenta muchas gracias!!!